# How to step into OpenCV source code in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2019

I've already installed OpenCV 4.2.0 on my computer, following [the guidance on its official website](https://docs.opencv.org/4.2.0/d3/d52/tutorial_windows_install.html). Then I configured it in my Visual Studio 2019, also following [the guidance on its offical website](https://docs.opencv.org/4.2.0/dd/d6e/tutorial_windows_visual_studio_opencv.html).I created a sample using OpenCV's function `imread`. It can run correctly.

The question is how I can jump into its source code rather than `.hpp` file, by hit ctrl + mouseleft on this function?

Another question is when I debug this project, I set breakpoint in the line where function `imread` located, and I press F11 to single step.It cannot step into where the function `imread` defines. I want to learn how the function works.

I have tried in Tools-> Options -> Debug -> Symbol check Microsoft Symbol Server, but it can only make my code unable to run.(maybe because my internet takes long time to connect to Microsoft Server).And in the same dialog I add `opencv_world420d.pdb` or change the directory of symbol cache.It cannot work for me.

I also have tried to copy `.pdb` files or other stuff. Please tell me how to do.Thanks

Comment: I think it's not possible, you compiled OpenCV and you are calling the symbols from the library. An dI guess you can only debug on the code you compile.

Comment: Maybe you actually have to compile in debug mode and use the debug libraries

Answer (score 0):

[Add path for pdb file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6CQZh.png)

Hi, I encountered the same problem as yours. However, after directly adding the directory path where the pdb file is, without caring "Microsoft Symbol Servers" , I succeed to step into opencv function.

Hope this helps you :)

[Succeed to visit opencv source file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9T18a.png)

Comment: Please do not post images of code or errors. Text is preferred so that we can try to reproduce the problem without having to re-type everything and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

Answer (score -3):

You shouldn't really need to step into 3rd party libraries code when debugging your code.

The easiest way to see what you want is to check the github repo with the source code.

https://github.com/opencv/opencv

Find the source file you're looking for, and look at the function you want to see.

Comment: I have no problem reading the source code. What I want to see is when I call the function what happens inside. The source code is too difficult for me.

Comment: Maybe you need to disable "Just My Code" in Visual Studio then, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/just-my-code?view=vs-2019